# Can I use require() to ensure several function calls to other contracts are successfully executed in sequence?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Or is the only way to do this:

> Use delegatecall/assembly to access non-variably-sized function return
>   values & validate that each function is executed successfully.

In other words:

Is the only way to verify the result of functions at runtime by checking out the state of the “Delegate” contract?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can be sure that everything in your single function is well serialised and runs in the order you expect it to. Flow control returns to your function when the "delegate" returns, and then you can carry on.

If you're writing both contracts you can.

```
contract Subordinate {

  function doSomething() public returns(bool success) {
    // ...
    return true;
  }
}

contract Coordinator {

  Subordinate s;

  function makeItHappen() public returns(bool success) {
    require(s.doSomething());
    require(s.doSomething()); // do it again
    // ... "s" definitely did something twice, in order. Carry on
    return true;
  }
}
```

It's a bit of style thing to habitually `returns(bool)`. It's useful from time to time.

Hope it helps.